# RestorePackages Error in NuGet.targets

Tags: nuget-package-restore

How do I resolve this error in an NuGet.targets file:

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\</SolutionDir>

    <!-- Enable the restore command to run before builds -->
    <RestorePackages Condition="  '$(RestorePackages)' == '' ">false</RestorePackages>
```

Where the RestorePackages tag has an error stating that the msbuild/2003 has an invalid child element.

I get the same type of error for tags:  NuGetToolsPath, PackagesProjectConfig, NuGetExePath, MsBuild, and DownloadNuGet

After these errors I get 17 cases of "unable to locate .....nuget\NuGet.exe in the 17 projects of this VS2013 solution for the MVCForum software downloaded from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Click Build->Clean Solution and right-click the solution and set to "Enable NuGet package restore".  Apparently this results in getting the correct copy of NuGet.exe.  After doing this, all the errors went away.